# Adding vector tiles to mapbox.js

Tags: mapbox, geo, mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

Mapbox JS has an extensive library of examples [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/), but what is missing is documentation on how to load vector tiles from Mapbox Studio.

In the upgraded Mapbox GL JS, this is clearly explained in the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/).

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "terrain-data",
    "type": "line",
    "source": {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
    },
    "source-layer": "contour",
    "layout": {
        "line-join": "round",
        "line-cap": "round"
    },
    "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ff69b4",
        "line-width": 1
    }
});
```

Where the url contains the `mapid` and the `source-layer` is the name of the layer.  So if `mapid` = abcd1234, my username is `testUser`, and my vector layer name is `testLayer` I would write:

```
"source": {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://testUser.abcd1234'
},
"source-layer": "testLayer",
```

This works perfectly in Mapbox GL JS, but what would the equivalent example be for loading mapbox vector tiles from Mapbox Studio in Mapbox JS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Mapbox JS is based on Leaflet 1+, then you can use http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html. Actually I find this plugin + Leaflet/Mapbox JS has certain advantages over gl js.